# List of iTunes Videos

Tags: iphone, objective-c, itunes

Is there any API's or some permissions to fetch the iTunes Videos list. So that we can see that video with own application.

I have already try to find an answer through a lot of requests on google, without success!

So, I would like to know if it's possible, and if yes how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to parse the RSS feeds in this site.

www.apple.com/rss

Answer (score 1):

Better yet, iTunes offers RSS feeds that are a bit more customizable to your needs:

http://itunes.apple.com/rss

You can narrow down the results to a specific country, get up to 300 results and even filter by genre if necessary.

More info can be found here:

http://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/resources/blog/introduction---rss-feed-generator.html